# What version of IE does Outlook 2003 use?

Tags: internet-explorer, email, outlook

I am running into some formatting issues while testing.  My email looks fine in IE9, so I am wondering what version Outlook 2003 uses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Outlook 2003 is installed for the first time, it uses the version of IE that is installed on that particular OS as it's rendering engine. From there, if IE6 is upgraded to IE7, Outlook will still use the original version of IE (in this case IE6).

If you don't have a version of IE6, I suggest using a tool like [Email on Acid](http://www.emailonacid.com) for testing.

Comment: Not true, MSHTML etc is a global system component that is in System32. What you are probably hitting is that they default to IE7 mode for third party apps that embed it.

Answer (score 1):

Actually for reasons best known to Microsoft it uses the Word rendering engine. I believe they cited something about security or some such at the time.

This is a very annoying decision as it means support for all sorts of CSS and HTML goodies is extremely lacking.

**EDIT:** Apologies that seems to be from 2007 onwards, but I will leave the answer here as it is probably still relevant as those with newer Outlooks will still have problems unless it is some internal email and you are sure everyone will have 2003.

It seems 2003 uses the IE6 render engine which is probably almost as annoying.